# Tesseract.js code avialable online is not working

Tags: javascript, tesseract.js

I'm trying this tesseract.js code available online, which is not working. I am not getting any output. I don't think it is recognizing any of the tesseract functions, despite including the CDN.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test ocr</title>
           <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/naptha/tesseract.js@v1.0.14/dist/tesseract.min.js'></script>
   </head>
     <body>
    <input type="button" id="go_button" value="Run" />
    <div id="ocr_results"> </div>
    <div id="ocr_status"> </div>
    <img id="img" src="image.png"/>
    <script>
document.getElementById("go_button")
            .addEventListener("click", function(e) 
{
                var url = document.getElementById("img").src;
                runOCR(url);
            });
        function runOCR(url) {
            Tesseract.recognize(url)
                 .then(function(result) {
                    document.getElementById("ocr_results")
                            .innerText = result.text;

                 }).progress(function(result) {
                    document.getElementById("ocr_status")
                            .innerText = result["status"] + " (" +
                                (result["progress"] * 100) + "%)";
                });

        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: do you have an `image.png` in the same path?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add comments yet, so as an answer: I tested your code and it does what it should do. Please check that your image.png is displayed correctly in your browser.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Image is displayed correctly as I checked. Now, when I click run, it displays the progress till "Initializing tesseract (100%)", and stops there. Nothing after that. I think it isn't recognizing the text despite the image having pretty clear text.

Comment: Is there any output in your browser console? After Initializing tesseract (100%) it tries to download training data. Maybe you have a problem downloading that. In my case he tries to download: https://tessdata.projectnaptha.com/3.02/eng.traineddata.gz